# Displaying the content of .json array into html using javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I am getting a json response from API url and i stored it in a `const data=await response.json()`
i figured out the data length by using `const data_length = data.length`
I tried to loop through the entire json object to get individual entries like so :

strava_api.js

```
async function getActivites(res){

    const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=${res.access_token}`
    const response = await fetch(activities_link)
    const data = await response.json()
    const data_length = data.length
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

     const newData=[data[i].type ,data[i].name, data[i].start_date, data[i].distance, data[i].elapsed_time, data[i].average_heartrate]
     document.getElementById('type').textContent = data[i].type
     document.getElementById('name').textContent = data[i].name
     document.getElementById('start_date').textContent = data[i].start_date
     document.getElementById('distance').textContent = data[i].distance
     document.getElementById('elapsed_time').textContent = data[i].elapsed_time
     document.getElementById('average_heartrate').textContent = data[i].average_heartrate
     //console.log(newData);

    }

}
```

Now i am trying to display this data in HTML :

index.html

```
<h1>Hello Strava developer</h1>
    <h2>Here is your activities data</h2>
    <p>
        Activity type : <span id="type"></span></br>
        Activity name : <span id="name"></span></br>
        Activity start date : <span id="start_date"></span></br>
        Activity distance : <span id="distance"></span></br>
        Activity elapsed time : <span id="elapsed_time"></span></br>
        Activity Avg.HR : <span id="average_heartrate"></span>
    </p>
```

Now i got the data displayed but only for the first object array, i have 30 arrays , How can i display them all ?

Comment: How is your ID-based code going to work with multiple data items?

Comment: try (data[i]).name as so on

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your development console? Is your access token valid?  You're looping over the returned JSON, but aren't creating any new nodes in your DOM. You'll just be overwriting everything with the next record until you reach the last row. This doesn't appear to be what you intended when using a loop.

Comment: @esqew now i got the data displayed but for the first array only , i need to display everything not the first array only.